# Working with CSV - DataSplits

Tags: powershell, csv, import

I have a script written that pulls a number of CSV files from an FTP server and downloads to a network location.

The content of this CSV file follows the example I have provided in this link
[File Example](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K4IEuZJFfjkspVK4a5vNv1ucJindMKkISZBAIctrO08/edit?usp=sharing)

In short working with this file I need to:

- Using the 12 characters (alpha-numeric) which follow `Ords:` on line two define a variable which will used later in a query. (A)

  > GB0000000001

  Would become

  ```
  $OrderVariable = "GB0000000001"
  ```

  I have read about

  ```
  .TrimStart([Characters_to_remove])
  ```

  but am unsure how it would skip the first row and then how I would remove everything following the next 12 letters.
- Using the entire line two information excluding the `Ords:` define this as a variable e.g.

  > GB0000000001 – Promotion Event

  would become

  ```
  $TitleEvent = "GB0000000001 – Promotion Event"
  ```

The CSV contains all the customers that an email needs to be sent to e.g.

```
D|300123123|BBA
D|300321312|DDS
D|A0123950|BBA 
D|A0999950|ZZG
```

These items I would expect to be written into a hashtable which I thought would be simple enough except I cannot find any way to exclude everything which precedes it.

```
$mytable   = Import-Csv -Path $filePath -Header D,Client,Suffix
$HashTable = @{}
foreach ($r in $mytable) {
    $HashTable[$r.Client] = $r.Data
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have managed to get most of this element into a variable with the following

```
$target = "\\Messaging"

cd $target
$Clients = Import-Csv example.txt | where {$_ -like "*D|*"} 

$Clients = $Clients[1..($Clients.count - 1)]
$Clients | Export-Csv "Test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But I cannot get it to import with custom headers or without the first "H|" delimitation...

***End of update 1***

I believe this is roughly what is going to be required as the only element that I will need to define and use in a later query is the Client themselves.

- The next would define all the text that remains as the message content

  > This is a Promotion Event and action needs to be taken by you.  The
  >
  > deadline for your instruction is 2pm on 12 September 2016.
  >
  > The deadline for this event has been extended.
  >
  > To notify us of your instruction you can send a secure message.

  This can differ on each occasion massively so cannot simply be a removal of X numbers of lines the content will always follow the `Ords:` (line two) and End at the start for the `D|` delimitation.

Most of the other code I need to put together I am 'fairly confident' with (famous last words) and have a fully working script that is pulling the files I need, I am just not great at working with .csv's when I have them.

Comment: The csv is produced by an external data provider, it is in a partial csv format with the first line being delimited and the client account numbers in a delimited format all other elements are non delimited.

Comment: The file could be split as pipe delimited but I had rightly or wrongly discounted that.  When it is imported as a delimited object all the "message" information falls into the first column which would have the header "H".  In this instance the second line would need to be removed and the last x rows which would read D, D, D for the number of clients in the file and finally end with T  The file header its self is what is contained within the second row of the data.  My apologies if I am not explaining this very well but that is the reason I did link to an example.

Answer (score 1):

The data format is flexible without a global table/grid structure so let's use regexps (the [breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/lC4mT8/1)), which is quite a universal method of parsing such texts.

```
$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('inputfile.txt', [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)

$data = ([regex]('ORDS: (?<order>.+?) [-–—] (?<title>.+)[\r\n]+' +
                 '(?<info>[\s\S]+?)[\r\n]+' +
                 '(?<clients>D\|[\s\S]+?)[\r\n]+' +
                 'T\|(?<T>\d+)')
    ).Matches($text) |
    forEach {
        $g = $_.groups
        @{
            order = $g['order'].value
            info = $g['info'].value -join ' '
            clients = $g['clients'].value -split '[\r\n]+' |
                where { $_ -match 'D\|(.+?)\|(.+)' } |
                forEach {
                    @{
                        id = $matches[1]
                        suffix = $matches[2]
                    }
                }
            T = $g['T']
        }
    }
```

`$data` is now a record (or an array of records if the file has multiple entries):

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> T                              000004
> info                           This is a Promotion Event and action needs to be take...
> order                          GB0000000001
> clients                        {System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Has...
> ```

`$data.clients` is an array of records:

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> id                             300123123
> suffix                         BBA
> id                             300321312
> suffix                         DDS
> id                             A0123950
> suffix                         BBA
> id                             A0999950
> suffix                         ZZG
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have gone about the solution in  a slightly different way that may not be as elegant but provides me with greater flexibility going forward.  I am just iterating through the last elements and then I will publish accordingly.  Help most appreciated!